# Copying rows from one sheet to others stops unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a big main table and I want from there to fill 10 smaller tables to have something like reports (working tables to print). I fill the working tables on different conditions and wrote script for that (thought it's the only way). If I run the script for only one table it works, but if I run it to fill all the tables it stops somewhere ( on different place everytime) unexpectedly and now I have only 4 rows. When the main table is used for work it will have maybe 300 rows.
This is the link for the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T6ujnZFdXYoC9n71RH8fm0EXKoyrUAYJGI-v5dwoDso/edit?usp=sharing

And this is the script

```
function doTables() {
var sheetNameToMoveFrom = "Главен лист";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//we get the speadsheet we are using
var sheetToMoveFrom = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveFrom);// we store the object of the sheet to move from
var theLastRow = sheetToMoveFrom.getLastRow(); //store the num of rows with content
var valueToWatchYES = "да";
var valueToWatchNO = "не";

var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo1 = "1.ряз за ламинат";
var sheetToMoveTo1 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo1);// we store the object of the sheet to move to
var columnNumberToWatch1 = 39; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var theLastRow1 = sheetToMoveTo1.getLastRow();
sheetToMoveTo1.deleteRows(3,theLastRow1);// delete all rows from the table that we will copy into, so if there is a change on some row to apply 
var theFreeRow1 = 3;

var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo2 = "2.ряз за кант";
var sheetToMoveTo2 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo2);// we store the object of the sheet to move to
var columnNumberToWatch21 = 15; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var columnNumberToWatch22 = 18; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var columnNumberToWatch23 = 22; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var theLastRow2 = sheetToMoveTo2.getLastRow();
sheetToMoveTo2.deleteRows(3,theLastRow2);// delete all rows from the table that we will copy into, so if there is a change on some row to apply
var theFreeRow2 = 3;

var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo3 = "3.закалено за ламиниране";
var sheetToMoveTo3 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo3);// we store the object of the sheet to move to
var columnNumberToWatch3 = 40; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var theLastRow3 = sheetToMoveTo3.getLastRow();
sheetToMoveTo3.deleteRows(3,theLastRow3);// delete all rows from the table that we will copy into, so if there is a change on some row to apply
var theFreeRow3 = 3;

var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo4 = "4.готов продукт за опаковане";
var sheetToMoveTo4 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo4);// we store the object of the sheet to move to
var columnNumberToWatch41 = 41; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var columnNumberToWatch42 = 42; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var theLastRow4 = sheetToMoveTo4.getLastRow();
sheetToMoveTo4.deleteRows(3,theLastRow4);// delete all rows from the table that we will copy into, so if there is a change on some row to apply
var theFreeRow4 = 3;

var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo5 = "5.опис за ишлемета";
var sheetToMoveTo5 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo5);// we store the object of the sheet to move to
var columnNumberToWatch5 = 32; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var theLastRow5 = sheetToMoveTo5.getLastRow();
sheetToMoveTo5.deleteRows(3,theLastRow5);// delete all rows from the table that we will copy into, so if there is a change on some row to apply
var theFreeRow5 = 3;

var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo6 = "6.опис стъкла за кантиране";
var sheetToMoveTo6 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo6);// we store the object of the sheet to move to
var columnNumberToWatch6 = 15; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var theLastRow6 = sheetToMoveTo6.getLastRow();
sheetToMoveTo6.deleteRows(3,theLastRow6);// delete all rows from the table that we will copy into, so if there is a change on some row to apply
var theFreeRow6 = 3;

var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo7 = "7.опис стъкла за пробиване";
var sheetToMoveTo7 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo7);// we store the object of the sheet to move to
var columnNumberToWatch7 = 18; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var theLastRow7 = sheetToMoveTo7.getLastRow();
sheetToMoveTo7.deleteRows(3,theLastRow7);// delete all rows from the table that we will copy into, so if there is a change on some row to apply
var theFreeRow7 = 3;

var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo8 = "8.опис стъкла за цифрова обработка";
var sheetToMoveTo8 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo8);// we store the object of the sheet to move to
var columnNumberToWatch8 = 22; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var theLastRow8 = sheetToMoveTo8.getLastRow();
sheetToMoveTo8.deleteRows(3,theLastRow8);// delete all rows from the table that we will copy into, so if there is a change on some row to apply
var theFreeRow8 = 3;

var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo9 = "9.опис стъкла за облепване";
var sheetToMoveTo9 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo9);// we store the object of the sheet to move to
var columnNumberToWatch91 = 27; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var columnNumberToWatch92 = 43; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var theLastRow9 = sheetToMoveTo9.getLastRow();
sheetToMoveTo9.deleteRows(3,theLastRow9);// delete all rows from the table that we will copy into, so if there is a change on some row to apply
var theFreeRow9 = 3;

var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo10 = "10.опис стъкла за ламиниране";
var sheetToMoveTo10 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo10);// we store the object of the sheet to move to
var columnNumberToWatch101 = 43; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var columnNumberToWatch102 = 5; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var theLastRow10 = sheetToMoveTo10.getLastRow();
sheetToMoveTo10.deleteRows(3,theLastRow10);// delete all rows from the table that we will copy into, so if there is a change on some row to apply
var theFreeRow10 = 3;

var rangeToCopy;
var rangeToRecieveCopy;

//loop through all the rows that the sheet we will copy from have and look for what matter for you
for(var i=1; i<=theLastRow; i++)
{
  //table 1
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch1).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("A"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,1);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("B"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,2);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("C"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,3);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("D"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,4);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("E"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,5);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("H"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,6);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("I"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,7);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("J"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,8);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("K"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,9);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("M"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,10);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("N"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,11);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      theFreeRow1++;
  }
  //table 2
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch21).getValue() == valueToWatchYES || sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch22).getValue() == valueToWatchYES || sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch23).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("A"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,1);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("B"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,2);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("C"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,3);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("D"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,4);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("E"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,5);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("F"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,6);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("G"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,7);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("K"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,8);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("M"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,9);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("N"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,10);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("P"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,11);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("T"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,12);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("Y"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,13);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      theFreeRow2++;
  }
  //table 3
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch3).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("A"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,1);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("B"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,2);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("C"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,3);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("D"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,4);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("E"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,5);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("H"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,6);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("I"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,7);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("J"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,8);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("K"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,9);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("M"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,10);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("N"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,11);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      theFreeRow3++;
  }
  //table 4
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch41).getValue() == valueToWatchYES || sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch42).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("A"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,1);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("B"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,2);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("C"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,3);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("D"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,4);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("E"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,5);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("H"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,6);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("I"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,7);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("J"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,8);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("K"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,9);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("M"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,10);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("N"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo4.getRange(theFreeRow4,11);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      theFreeRow4++;
  }
  //table 5
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch5).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("A"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,1);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("B"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,2);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("C"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,3);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("D"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,4);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("E"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,5);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("F"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,6);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("H"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,7);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("J"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,8);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("K"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,9);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("M"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,10);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("AG"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,11);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("AH"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,12);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("AI"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,13);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("AJ"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,14);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("AK"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,15);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("AL"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo5.getRange(theFreeRow5,16);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      theFreeRow5++;
  }
  //table 6
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch6).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("A"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,1);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("B"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,2);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("C"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,3);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("D"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,4);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("E"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,5);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("F"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,6);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("G"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,7);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("M"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,8);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("P"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,9);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("Q"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,10);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("R"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,11);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("K"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo6.getRange(theFreeRow6,12);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      theFreeRow6++;
  }
  //table 7
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch7).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("A"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,1);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("B"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,2);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("C"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,3);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("D"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,4);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("E"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,5);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("S"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,6);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("T"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,7);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("U"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,8);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("I"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,9);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("J"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,10);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("K"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo7.getRange(theFreeRow7,11);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      theFreeRow7++;
  }
  //table 8
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch8).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("A"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,1);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("B"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,2);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("C"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,3);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("D"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,4);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("E"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,5);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("I"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,6);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("J"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,7);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("K"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,8);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("W"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,9);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("X"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,10);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("Y"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,11);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      rangeToCopy = sheetToMoveFrom.getRange("Z"+i);
      rangeToRecieveCopy = sheetToMoveTo8.getRange(theFreeRow8,12);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(rangeToRecieveCopy);
      theFreeRow8++;
  }
  }
  }
  function onEdit(e) {
      if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "други" || e.range.rowStart != 1 || e.range.columnStart != 9) return;
      if(e.source.getSheetByName("други").getRange(1,9).getValue() == "да"){
        doTables();
        e.source.getSheetByName("други").getRange(1,9).setValue("готово");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked your execution transcript when it fails?

Comment: The problem is not in the logic of the script, it fails at different place everytime

Comment: So is it timing out?

Answer (score 0):

If your script is timing out (i.e. exceeding the 6 minute script limit) then here's something you could try.  I only modified the first three sections but it looks like there's some repetition.  I'm guessing that if you were to use getValues and setValues and parameterize your sheets (perhaps in an array) you could probably get this entire function down to less than 50 lines of code that would run an order of magnitude faster than it is now.  If I had all of the data in front of me and I understood the language so that I could get a contextual understanding of what's going on I could probably do it in less than 3 hours.  Some of the other programmers could probably do it in less than that.

```
for(var i=1; i<=theLastRow; i++)
{
  //table 1
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch1).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
    rangeToCopy=sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,1,1,14);
    var valuesToCopy=rangeToCopy.getValues();
    valuesToCopy.splice(5,2);
    valuesToCopy.splice(9,1);
    rangeToReceiveCopy=sheetToMoveTo1.getRange(theFreeRow1,1,1,11);
    rangeToReceiveCopy.setValues(valuesToCopy);
    theFreeRow1++;
  }
  //table 2
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch21).getValue() == valueToWatchYES || sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch22).getValue() == valueToWatchYES || sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch23).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
    rangeToCopy=sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,1,1,14);
    var valuesToCopy=rangeToCopy.getValues();
    valuesToCopy.splice(7,2);
    valuesToCopy.splice(9,1);
    rangeToReceiveCopy=sheetToMoveTo2.getRange(theFreeRow2,1,1,13);
    rangeToReceiveCopy.setValues(valuesToCopy);
    theFreeRow2++;
  }
  //table 3
  if(sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,columnNumberToWatch3).getValue() == valueToWatchYES)
  {
    rangeToCopy=sheetToMoveFrom.getRange(i,1,1,14);
    var valuesToCopy=rangeToCopy.getValues();
    valuesToCopy.splice(5,2);
    valuesToCopy.splice(9,1);
    rangeToReceiveCopy=sheetToMoveTo3.getRange(theFreeRow3,1,1,11);
    rangeToReceiveCopy.setValues(valuesToCopy);
    theFreeRow3++;
  }
 }
```